# Why the set of points satisfying (2x-x²-y²)*(x²+y²-x)>0 is the same of the set with condition ((2x-x²-y²)>o and (x²+y²-x)>0)?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

Why the set of points on $\Bbb R^{2}$ satisfying $(2x-x²-y²)(x²+y²-x)>0$ is the same of the set of all elements on $\Bbb R^{2}$ with condition $((2x-x²-y²)>0 $ and $(x²+y²-x)>0)$, i think that the first set includes elements that is not in the last one, for example the elements satisfying $((2x-x²-y²)<0 $ and $(x²+y²-x)<0)$

Also how can i proof that these set must be open?

Thank you.

Comment: Regarding proving that the sets are open:  What have you tried?  WHat isn't working?

Comment: oh right, i am sorry, well unfortunately i am not familiarized with formal proofs on topology, but i know something, then i tried to work out these thing, for example the theorem whose states that if f is continuous the the inverse image of an open set is also an open set, i think that the thing here is take the function to be the bigger product, and after see the image of the positive reals under this inverse, but i am not sure, it appears that exists another way or another theorem.

Comment: i have a thought that if you use the axiom of specification on a open set, and the condition that you use generate a open set by itself then the final set is also open, but i could not prove it :(, thank you very much

Comment: Is $(0,\infty)$ an open set (in $\Bbb{R}$ with the usual topology)?  Are multiplication and addition continuous?  Just trying to figure out what tools you do and don't have...

Comment: thank you for the help and attention @EricTowers.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the set of solutions of the other system:
$$\begin{cases}2x-x^2-y^2<0,\\x^2+y^2-x<0\end{cases}$$
is empty.

This an open set because it's the intersection of the inverse images of the open set $]0,+\infty[$ by two polynomial functions, which  are continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x^2+y^2-x < 0$. Then we necessarily have $x > 0$, and hence $2x-x^2-y^2 = x-(x^2+y^2-x) > x + 0 > 0$, and we've showed there exist no solutions for that system.

Comment: Oops, typo. Sorry and thanks.